# cocos2d for iphone: lines antialiasing

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've spent a lot of time looking for this and try to adapt code but as I'm new to cocos2d I really need your help.

So what I am trying to do is to draw a straight and anti aliased line with v2.0, as I'm stuck with a single ugly aliased line.

Thanks a lot!